# How to pad strings inside curly braces with odd number of character with a single space?

Tags: vim

We have many `\foo{something}`. As the string inside the curly braces contains odd number of character, we want to add a space after the string. The result will be `\foo{something }`. We only want odd number of characters only. For example, in `\foo{string}` the string inside the curly braces has even number of character, then we do not add a space.

What I have tried:

1. a dot means a character, two dots means two characters
2. asterisk means repeat 0 or more times
3. Then, `[..]*.` means 1, 3, 5 ... characters.
4. Then, `\foo{[..]*.}` will be my matching sequence.
5. Then, `:%s/\foo{[..]*.}/\foo{[..]*. }/g` will add the space we want.

But we failed.

Comment: Are you trying to align something?

Comment: @Stefan Not really. `\foo` is a macro but it is too stupid it failed sometimes, if the argument contains even number of characters, say 6 the result is fine (3+3) , but for odd length, say 7, sometimes it is (4+3) correct but sometimes it is (3+4). the `\foo` is intended to return (4+3). All characters inside are fullwidth, and I will actually add a fullwidth space rather than a half width space. We are preparing some CJK documents.

Comment: A bracket expression [],  matches a single character that is contained within the brackets. For example, [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c".
The regex '\\foo\{((\w{2})*)\w\}' (here written for python re, but I guess same same could be applied to vim) matches '\foo{something}' but not \foo{somethin}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
:%s/\v[(\{(\w{2})*) ]@<!}/ }/g
```

break down:

```
%s           " run substitute on every line
\v           " very magic mode
[(\{(\w{2})*) ] " matches every `{` followed by an equal number of word 
characters and space, since you don't want to add a space again everytime 
you run it.
@<!}         " negative lookahead, matches all } not following the pattern before
```

**Update**

To solve the precise problem as you can read in the comments, the following command helps.

```
g/^\\foo/s/\v(\{([^}]{2})*)@<!}/ }/g
```

Changes:

```
 g/^\\foo/...    " only run it on lines starting with \foo
 [^}]            " it does now match all characters between { and } not only word
 characters.
```

Pitfalls: won't work correct with multiple braces on the line ( `\foo{"hello{}"}` and `\foo{string} {here it would also match}` f.e. will fail). if one of these is a problem. just tell me

Comment: But the pattern must be following the `\foo`. Sorry I haven't made it clear in my question.

Comment: nice idea, but I would consider to change the `\w` by something else, E.g. `#` is not a `\w`.

Comment: And, even if the last character is a space, we still want another space. We only want to add space if the string contains odd number of characters. e.g. A `\foo{AB }` will be `\foo{AB ​ }`.

Comment: And, `\foo{ABC }` is four characters and we won't want to add one more character. The code does add.

Comment: @HYC Please specifiy exactly what can be in the string, if you need us to adept the specific regex. Please see the upate, as you can see, it has no the same construct as Kent's answer `[ ^}]`

Comment: also in character class`[...]`, you don't need the escape unless for `[ ,]` those chars.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo thanks. I don't understand the command but it does the correct job now.

Answer (score 2):

This cmd should do:

```
:%s/\\foo{\zs[^}]\+\ze}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '$', len(submatch(0))%2?' ':'','g')/
```

Comment: It seems the piece of code works well. will test some more.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\\\w\+{\([^}]\{2}\)*[^}]\zs\ze}/ /g
```

Explanation:

Find pairs of characters (`\([^}]\{2}\)*`) followed by another character (`[^}]`) in between a macro `\\\w\+{...}`. Then do a substitution adding an additional space.

Glory of details:

- `\\\w\+{...}` find macros of the pattern `\foo{...}`
- Look for character that does not match an ending curly brace, `[^}]`
- Look for pairs of non-`}`'s, `\([^}]\{2}\)*`
- Find an odd length string by finding pairs and then finding one more, `\([^}]\{2}\)*[^}]`
- Use `\zs` and `\ze` to set where the start and end of the match
- Use a space in the replacement portion of the substitution to add additional space and thereby making the string even in length

Fore more help see:

```
:h :s
:h :range
:h /\[]
:h /\(
:h /\zs
:h /\w
:h /star
:h /\+
```